# SQL Server CE - ROW_NUMBER

Tags: sql-server-ce

I don't know what is wrong with this code, it's giving me error for a day now:

```
select row_number() over(order by s.title) as rowNumber, s.id 
from story as s
```

Table Definition:

```
id       bigint
title    nvarchar(100)
content  ntext
```

Database: SQL Server Compact 4.0.8482.1

Error:

> There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number = 1,Token line offset = 22,Token in error = over ]

WHAT I DID SO FAR:

I've searched here in SO for same problem but the solution is not applicable to mine, I need `row_number` function so badly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As ErikEJ already mentioned - `ROW_NUMBER` simply doesn't exist in SQL Server Compact Edition - not even in the newest 4.0 version.

However, if you're trying to use `ROW_NUMBER` to page your data, SQL Server Compact Edition 4.0 does support server-side paging through new keywords that will show up in SQL Server 2012, too - see [this blog post here](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/jacob/archive/2010/07/13/support-for-paging-queries-in-sql-server-ce-4-0.aspx) for all the details.

You should be able to write something like:

```
SELECT (columns)
FROM Story s
ORDER BY Title
OFFSET 20 ROWS 
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: You're right, I'm trying to create pagination... I've tried offset-fetch but I got an error yesterday so I thought it won't work. I'll try it again and inform you right away.

Comment: It works! I used this `offset @0 rows fetch next @1 rows only` instead of my old query `offset (@0- 1) * @1 rows fetch next @1 rows only`, I computed `@0` in my app. It seems like computations are not allowed in SQL CE too, is it? Does SQL CE consider `(@0- 1) * @1` as subquery?

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server CE does not have row_number. and it also cannot do scalar sub-queries which can also be used to get rownumber.

but you can do inequality joins... counting joins.

this would give you a rownumber.

```
select count(r.id) as Row_Number, s.id 
from story as s
    inner join story as r
        on s.id >= r.id
group by s.id
```

Comment: Superb. How did you come to this solution @guymella? I can not follow the reasoning on the inequality join

Answer (score 1):

There is no row_number in SQL Server Compact - could you use IDENTITY (not sure what you are trying to do) ?

Comment: Sir, I'm trying to create pagination but got an error, upon debugging I came across this section of my query and it seems like it is the problem so I tried to make a test. I'll try marc_s's solution.